# How to attach express-session req.session.user to chai-http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chai, express-session

My API uses `express-session` and authenticates any request based on the presence of the `req.session.user` object, as shown below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    console.log('Authenticated request\n');
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('Request not authenticated, request rejected\n');    
    res.status(403).json({'message': 'Request rejected'});;
  }
});
```

I'm writing tests for my API with `chai-http` as shown below:

```
describe('test', function(){
  it('/test', function(done){
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/test')
    .end(function(err, res){
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
    });
  });
});
```

**Question**
 I want the requests to pass the authentication above. How can I add the `.session.user` object to my `chai-http` requests? Should I be using `supertest` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using passport for the auth, if so see below. IF NOT: check out this implementation of Passport-stub to see how it hijacks the middleware to fake the user:

https://github.com/gtramontina/passport-stub/blob/master/src/passport-stub.coffee

Using this technique you can insert middleware into the app to fake the user

If you're using passport:

How to use passport-stub

I checked out https://github.com/gtramontina/passport-stub

Here's my test for the `/users` route which is protected:

```
//During the test the env variable is set to test
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var expect = chai.expect

var passportStub = require('passport-stub');

var User = require.main.require('models/User');

// https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#7-the-wrapper
var app = require.main.require('app');



chai.use(chaiHttp);

passportStub.install(app);


describe('Users Controller', (done) => {

  var user, nock, github, mockToken, githubHost;


  beforeEach((done) => { //Before each test we reset the database
    User.query().del().then(() => {
      var params = {name: 'bonzo', authtype: 'github', authid: '12345678'}
      // Create a user so the db isn't empty
      // May help us uncover odd bugs
      new User(params).save()
        .then((bonzo) => {
          user = bonzo;
          done();
        })
    })
  });

  describe('index', () => {
    describe('without user', () => {
        it('it should redirect to github.com home page', (done) => {
          chai.request(app)
              .get('/users')
              .redirects(0)
              .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.headers['location']).to.match(/^\//);
                done();
              });
        });
    });

    describe('with user', () => {
        it('it should display users list', (done) => {

          passportStub.login({
            get: function(){ return 'bonzo'; }
          });

          chai.request(app)
              .get('/users')
              .redirects(0)
              .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.text).to.match(/bonzo/);
                done();
              });
        });
    });
  });
});
```